# python matplotlib mplot3d code for dancing landscape

Tags: python, 3d, matplotlib, complexity-theory

I try to write the code for a animated dancing landscape. The landscape could look just like the matlab icon and the 'hills' should slowely rise and fall and new hills should appear. The lanscape is to illustrated the concept of complexity. Thanks. Arthur

Comment: Should it be interactive?  What do you ultimately need, a video file, a gif, an animated icon?  You should show what you've created so far and why it does not meet your needs.

Comment: I am trying to rework this example http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo3.html

Comment: Interactive would be nice but initially a running app which generates random dancing landscapes is fine.

Comment: What's wrong with the example? Why can't you modify it to your liking?

Comment: I can't get the 'formula' for the matlab icon like landscape.

Comment: The term "looks like landscape" is not specific enough to be much guidance for concrete|linear|sequential-types.  What in particular do you like about the matlab icon?  the coloring?  the fact that there is a flat water-like region?  the fact that the "mountain" has ridges and valleys?  This: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_landscape is what i think of when you say landscape, but it does not resemble the matlab icon at all.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/mplot3d/wire3d_animation_demo.html) example should help, but for the filled surface (`plot_surface`) is very slow. Maybe a better solution would be [Mayavi2](http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/).